# Socket.io not working with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, gunicorn, pm2

I have a nicely working django website which is being served by gunicorn and nginx(as a proxy server), now i want to add chat mechanism in that website using socket.io and nodejs. The problem is that the chat works perfectly fine when i connect socketio directly to nodejs server(which is listening on port 5000) but when i try to use nginx to proxy the socketio request to nodejs it doesn't work.

Here is my nginx file in /sites-enabled/ dir

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/static;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/file.sock;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

BTW I am using pm2 to manage nodejs (if it makes any difference).

EDIT:

```
server.js:


var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var fs = require('fs');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connected');


    socket.on('question', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        soc.emit('question', data);
    });

    socket.on('advice', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        soc.emit('advice', data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});




client.js

var socket  = io('http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/');


socket.on('question', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});


socket.on('advice', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

$('#send').click(function() {

    var msg     = $('#msg').val();

    if (msg == '') {$('#msg').focus();}
    else{

        data = {msg:msg};
        socket.emit('question', data);

        var msg = $('#msg').val('').focus();
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can you define _"it doesn't work"_? HTTP errors? JS errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors. The website is working as normal. No errors in console.log(browser) and i can see the output of nodejs server with 'pm2 logs app_name' after successful  client-server connection,  so the connection is established . Is there any other place where i can find errors?

Comment: The client-server connection is successful but the messages are not getting transmitted to other clients.

Comment: Does the Node server receive the messages sent from the clients? You can also start the Node server in debugging mode so it'll log more info: `env DEBUG=* node server.js` (or the Windows equivalent)

Comment: No, connection is successful, but the node server is not receiving the messages.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the server-side and client-side code?

Comment: @robertklep I have added contents of server.js and client.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL that you're using for the client is incorrect:

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/');
```

Adding a path (in this case, `/socket.io/`) has a special meaning in connection strings: it reflects the [namespace](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) that you want the client to connect to.

Since you're not using namespaces, you should leave it off:

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1/');
// Or possibly even just this:
// var socket = io();
```

Comment: Thank you! I about lost my mind with this one.